# WSL2 GUI Apps without X Server

Tags: x11, windows-subsystem-for-linux

[This post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/whats-new-in-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux-september-2020/#gui-apps) indicated back in September that WSL2 would soon support GUI apps without needing a third-party xserver.

However, I've not been able to find any more up-to-date references to this or whether it's made it into any insider builds (and if so, how to enable it).

Does anyone know what state this is in?

Answer (score 0):

Not yet.  You can view the WSL release notes for Preview builds available to Insiders [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/release-notes).  There's only been one feature release ([21286](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/release-notes#build-21286) since that blog post, and there's no mention of it.

Kind of looking forward to that one myself, as I would like GUI support in WSL, but not enough to be bothered with the convoluted configuration that is needed right now for third-party X Servers.

Just assuming at this point that it's not going to make it into an H1 2021 release if it hasn't made Preview/Insider yet.